What's the logic behind the definition of unreal in advaita vedanta?
From what I have studied, unreal in advaita vedanta is defined as something on which any of the following limitations applies:

Limitation in space: It exists here but not there or vice versa.
Limitation in time: It only exist for a finite amount of time. Basically, anything which has birth and death.
Limitation in object: It is this but not that.

Why reality can't have these limitations? What's the logic behind these limitations?

@User29449 But why is God defined as this in Tait. Upn.? Why is it not possible for God/reality to be limited in time, space and object? Limitation in time can be easily understood that if anything is temporary it can't be real. But what's stopping the reality to be limited in space and object?

But now this seems like a forced definition instead of logical. You are already assuming that some full-fledged liberation is possible and then to defend this statement you are saying God is infinite. It should be the other way around. First we should be able to know that God is infinite and then we can say there is something like full-fledged liberation possible.

space , time objects are bereft of any  objective reality ,  independent of an individual s  perception/experience, causal role,  rather they are mostly influenced  by the observers position , mostly attributed to mind/senses.Being so ,vedanta is more towards exploring  inwards the nature of consciousness contrasted to understanding external reality thru  senses. Relativism in physics could draw an analogy for a demonstration .Space time and  object should be considered subjective reality, thus  both real as well as unreal .

You might want to read the Tripura Rahasya (there's a good english translation available in paper, and online as a pdf). Of course, not to forget the works of Shankara, the Panchadasi, Yoga Vasistha and others of that category. I specifically mentioned the Tripura Rahasya only because I find it very concise and comfortably inclusive of all arguments in works of that category, all in a relatively shorter text. It is in the form of a conversation between Dattatreya and Parashurama.
